# Who wrote Ravana kaviyam?

Tags: ravana

Need answers to the following questions in order to clear my doubts:

- Who was the writer of Raavana Kaviyam?
- What was the reason to write it?
- To which state does the author belong to?

Comment: I have corrected your spelling and grammar. Please pay attention to this next time.

Comment: thanks wikash. am not well good in english

Answer (score 2):

It has been written by [**Pulavar Kulanthai**](https://ta.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%AE%AA%E0%AF%81%E0%AE%B2%E0%AE%B5%E0%AE%B0%E0%AF%8D_%E0%AE%95%E0%AF%81%E0%AE%B4%E0%AE%A8%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%A4%E0%AF%88) and was first published in 1946. Later a ban was made on June 2, 1948 and it was removed in the year 1971.

In Tamil,

[TamilWikipedia](https://ta.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%AE%87%E0%AE%B0%E0%AE%BE%E0%AE%B5%E0%AE%A3_%E0%AE%95%E0%AE%BE%E0%AE%B5%E0%AE%BF%E0%AE%AF%E0%AE%AE%E0%AF%8D)

[Tamilvu.org](http://www.tamilvu.org/courses/degree/a011/a0114/html/A0114331.htm)